# Is there way to automatically ls after changing into a directory using autocd in zsh?

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

I have `autocd` set in my `.zshrc` which works as expected, but I want to automatically run `ls` every time I use it. I can do something like this:

```
function cd {
    builtin cd "$@" && ls --color=auto
    }
```

to `ls` every time I explicitly use 'cd', but I want it to also work if I just type the name of a directory.
Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you defined a function with the predefined name `chpwd`, it is executed every time your working directory changes.

This behavour is described in the zsh man pages in the chapter "SPECIAL FUNCTIONS"